# Katalon Studio: how to use regex to identify objects by attributes?

Tags: regex, katalon-studio

If I try to identify objects in Katalon Studio (e.g. using the Object Spy) by "Selection Method: Attributes" then I can find successfully for example a logout button by the combination "text > equals > Logout". The xpath expression for this selection is: "//*[(text() = 'Logout' or . = 'Logout')]"

However trying the same using regex (i.e. "text > matches regex > Logout", resulting in xpath "//*[(matches(text(), 'Logout') or matches(., 'Logout'))]" does not find anything. Even stronger: using ".*" or similar as regex also does not find anything. I tried this with Firefox and Chrome both with no result.

I didn't find hints about this issue during research on the Internet.
Any ideas what I did wrong or how I can get regular expresion working for object selection?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Using+Regex+in+Katalon+Studio?

Comment: Thanks Mate for the tip. However, the link contains infrormation about how to use regex in Katalon programmatically whereas I was looking for a solution to get regex working in the Katalon GUI. If I won`t succeed with this, I will consider your info and will try to solve it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's a bug, matches in xpath selectors in OR is not working.
https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/7680/test-object-with-xpath-selector-using-matches-function-never-works